# ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, quantitative-finance

This Code, Takes 2 co-ordinates for a straight line from google finance and places 3rd point on the same line at some distance.

```
 import datetime as dt
 from datetime import timedelta as td
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from matplotlib import style
 import pandas as pd
 import pandas_datareader.data as web
 import numpy as np

 start = dt.datetime(2017, 7, 1)
 end = dt.datetime(2017, 3, 1)

 # retrieving data from google
 df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'google', start, )

 Dates = df.index
 Highs = df['High'] # Getting only the values from the 'High' Column.

 Highest_high = np.amax(Highs)  # returns the Highest value
      for i, h in enumerate(Highs):
           if h == Highest_high :
              Highests_index = i
 #Highests_index = Highs.argmax()  # returns the index of Highest value

 Highest_high_2 = sorted(Highs)[-2]
 for i, j in enumerate(Highs):
      if j == Highest_high_2 :
         Highests_index_2 = i

 #================Problem Maybe starting from here========================

 x = [Highests_index, Highests_index_2]
 y = [Highest_high, Highest_high_2]
 coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

 polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
 # the np.linspace lets you set number of data points, line length.
 x_axis = np.linspace(3,Highests_index_2 + 1, 3)
 y_axis = polynomial(x_axis)

 plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
 plt.plot(x[0], y[0], 'go')
 plt.plot(x[1], y[1], 'go')
 plt.plot(Dates, Highs)
 plt.grid('on')
 plt.show()
```

the following error occurs with lots of Traceback

> dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
>   ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

The above code works well when I just plot the numeric values without using datetime and pandas. I think the issue might be in datetime or in matplotlib.

I know this question might look duplicate, but I cannot relate my problem to any other solutions here.

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to matplotlib's inability to find the location of x-axis value along the x-axis.

The plot from the first two lines has numeric values for x-axis, whereas the third line is trying to plot a `datetime` on the same axis. While plotting the third line `plt.plot(Dates, Highs)`, matplotlib tries to find the x-axis location for the date and fails with the error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add to the answers here and possibly clarify why this may occur, for anyone visiting this in the future.

The `ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1` error can occur when an axis is specified to display as a time or date, but `matplotlib` cannot interpret the data for that axis as either type.

For example, if the following is plotted:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.plot(x, y, '-k')
```

It will generate the aforementioned error, as the data input to the x axis is a list of integers, and the `axis.xaxis_date()` function requires *datetime* objects.

To correct this the x-axis data must be *datetime* objects:

```
date_str = [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 16, 1, 0, 2), datetime.datetime(2020 10, 15, 12,18,31),datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 21, 18, 3, 6) ...]
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, Actually the error occured due to the 3rd last line. i deleted the `plt.plot()Dates, Highs)` And everything Worked like Charm!